# Passing data from parent to child not working conditionally - Angular 7/8

Tags: angular, angular7

I am working on an Angular 7/8 application. I created a Custom `Select` element as a component. Wherever I integrate the component, I pass two things to it.

1 - The `items` array that the select element should display as options.

2 - A placeholder which shows the name i.e. `Select an Option` etc.

I am using `@Input()` and `@Output()` to interact between the child and parent, and it works perfectly for me.

What I am doing is, I have shown one `<app-select></app-select>` element in the parent and the other is shown on the basis of when a user selects an option from the first `<app-select></app-select>`. For example, in the first `select` there is `Monthly and Yearly` options when a user selects `Monthly` then one type of data is loaded in the second `select` element, otherwise, on yearly option, another type of data is shown, and here the problem occurs.

Whenever any of the options `Monthly or Yearly` is selected, the `items` are shown and the placeholder is set, but when I try to choose the second option, the placeholder changes but the data doesn't get binded to the view, and the `items` from first selection is shown. I don't know what is the problem.

**The `select` Selectors**

```js
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 cp-sec">
   <app-select [items]='paymentBasisItems' [ph]="pbPh" (selectedItem)='paymentBasisSelected($event)'></app-select>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 cp-sec" *ngIf="isPaymentBasisSelected">
   <app-select [items]='paymentTimeItems' [ph]="ptPh" (selectedItem)='paymentTimeSelected($event)'></app-select>
</div>
```

**The Variables**

```js
  public paymentBasisItems: Array<any>;
  public pbPh: string;
  public paymentTimeItems: Array<any>;
  public ptPh: string;
```

**To Initialize the First `Select`**

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    this.pbPh = 'Select Payment Basis';
    this.paymentBasisItems = ['Monthly', 'Yearly'];
  }
```

**When an Option is Selected from the first `Select`**

```js
  paymentBasisSelected(event: any) {
    if (event === 'Monthly') {
      this.isPaymentBasisSelected = true;
      this.ptPh = 'Select Number Of Months';
      this.paymentTimeItems = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11];
    } else if (event === 'Yearly') {
      this.isPaymentBasisSelected = true;
      this.ptPh = 'Select Number Of Years';
      this.paymentTimeItems = ['select', 'a', 'year', 'nadeem', 'khan'];
    } else {
      this.isPaymentBasisSelected = false;
    }
  }
```

**Component Code for `select`**

```js
//Template
<div class="an-select">
    <div class="ans-head waves-effect waves-dark" (click)="toggleOpenSelect($event)" data-an-selected>{{ph}}</div>
    <div class="ans-opts">
        <div class="option waves-effect waves-light" *ngFor="let item of selectItems" (click)="optionSelected(item)">{{item}}</div>
    </div>
</div>





//Code
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-select',
  templateUrl: './select.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./select.component.scss']
})
export class SelectComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  @Input() items;
  @Input() ph;

  @Output() selectedItem = new EventEmitter();

  public selectItems: Array<any>;
  public selectPh: string;
  public currEle;
  public currEleShown = false;

  toggleOpenSelect(event) {


    this.currEle = event.target;
    if (!this.currEleShown) {
      (this.currEle.parentNode as any).querySelector('.ans-opts').style.display = 'block';
      this.currEleShown = true;
    } else if (this.currEleShown) {
      (this.currEle.parentNode as any).querySelector('.ans-opts').style.display = 'none';
      this.currEleShown = false;
    }
  }

  optionSelected(item) {
    this.ph = item;
    this.selectedItem.emit(item);
    (this.currEle.parentNode as any).querySelector('.ans-opts').style.display = 'none';
    this.currEleShown = false;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.selectItems = this.items;
    this.selectPh = this.ph;
  }

}
```

**When I select Monthly, the data get propagated**
[image]

**When I Select Yearly, the placeholder of second select changes but not data, and also it's reflected in the view, you can check the console.**
[image]

Comment: First - check if there are no errors in the console  as this may "stop" change detection/apply process

Comment: No errors at all @Antoniossss

Comment: Include component code of `app-select `.

Comment: Maybe you are not hitting here `} else if (event === 'Yearly') {` and going to `else` ?

Comment: I checked that too, it's working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add another component lifecycle method: ngOnChanges, where you basically do the same like in ngOnInit.

Alternatively, get rid of 'selectItems' and 'selectPh', and use 'items' and 'ph' directly (also in the template)

Comment: Perfect, that worked for me. and thank you for the suggestions.